# How do I create a range from a cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example:

```
 A      B      

7926    3     FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7970,"=0")
7926    3     FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7971,"=0")
7926    3     FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7972,"=0")
7926    3     FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7973,"=0")
7974    148   FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7974,"=0")
7974    148   FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7975,"=0")
7974    148   FROM     =COUNTIF(AQ$7926:AQ7976,"=0")
```

How do I change the starting row of a range based on a cell value on A?

Comment: I don't know what your second edit was for, but *please* check your formatting. There's a preview – use it! And don't write in caps lock.

Comment: Ups, Caps lock is my mistake, sorry for that. Thanks slhck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood well your question but are you looking for the [`INDIRECT`](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) formula?

If in cell `A1`, you add the value `B1` and in cell `B1` you have `Got it`.

The formula: 
`=INDIRECT(A1)` will return `Got it`

You can use it in your formula.